# Drop down navigation blocked by embeded youtube video

Tags: html, css

I have embeded a youtube video on my page under the navigation menu. The drop down menu is falling behind the video.

I have tried the wmode="transparent" and it isnt resolving my issue. I have tried &wmode=transparent & ?wmode=transparent behind the youtube link also with no success.

I would appreciate your advice.

My Html code is:

```
  <div class="video-container2">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fr7Haxh4Si0" wmode="transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```

My CSS is:

```
  .video-container2 {
              position: relative;
              padding-bottom: 56.25%;
              padding-top: 20px; 
              height: 0; 
              overflow: hidden;
             }

  .video-container2 iframe,
  .video-container2 object,
  .video-container2 embed {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 90%;
              height: 50%;
              margin-left: 0px;
              margin-bottom: 5px;
              }
```

Comment: have you checked the z-index of the header?

Comment: I havent added any z-index as yet. Im just learning how to code

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp
Set a higher value of z-index for the dropdown menu, and lower z-index for the video.

Comment: can you provided your html code?

Comment: oops i will edit, its hidden one sec

Comment: thanks all, the addition of a Z index fixed my issue most appreciated

Comment: Hi @KellieBottrell - Congrats and well done on getting it fixed! - please add that as an answer (along with the fixed CSS as an example) to this question and mark it as accepted so that future users will have a frame of reference!

Comment: @Frits could you let me know how to do it from a comment please?

Comment: Don't worry Kellie, @Frutis has already been kind enough to do it for you :) if you haven't yet, remember to up vote his answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Frits suggested adding a bit more detailed answer as a reference to my comment.

```
.video-container2 {
    z-index: -1;
    }
.dropdown_menu {
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing z-index of video container to 0  and Z-index of navigation to 99